# BC command not working in CYGWIN

Tags: cygwin, bc

I have downloaded `CygWin(32-bit)` and installed (on `Windows 7 32 bit System`) today to run shell script but i found one problem that bc command isn't working.
I am getting error `-bash: bc: command not found`. So please help me out!

[image]

Comment: `bc` can be installed with the command `apt-cyg install bc`.

Comment: There might be an alternative in bash shell syntax (I'm not talking old school, like expr, I mean modern bash)?  I'm looking to run a list of sums, one per line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to select the `bc` package for installation from the "Select Packages" window.
By default setup installs only base category that is ~ 50 packages,
while the full availability is ~ 4000.

https://cygwin.com/packages/x86/bc/bc-1.06.95-2

Answer (score 13):

**On Windows** Cygwin, run setup.exe and search for "bc" in the "Math" category, click on it and hit Next to install.

[image: Cygwin Setup]

**On Unix/Linux** you'll probably be needed to install this package Using:

```
sudo apt install bc
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that `bc` is not installed by default on Cygwin, and you will need to install it manually. [This link](https://superuser.com/questions/41093/installing-cygwin-packages-from-the-command-line) might help you.

DISCLAIMER: I have never used Cygwin.

Comment: I have added it in re-installation but it isn't working BTW thank you for your reply and i have already visited that site. :)

Comment: Hmmm... what does `which bc` say?