# Is there any other way around installing make on Cygwin without setting up anything over?

Tags: makefile, cygwin

Make can't be called on my Cygwin terminal. Some searching and browsing tell me to re-install Cygwin and tick on the Developmental packages. 
But I don't want to start from the scratch, again. Python has pip, what is the same package manager for cygwin?

Comment: If you want to have control over what cygwin downloads, run the cygwin installer (setup*.exe), with option of "Download Without Installing" ticked; with "Keep" ticked (to not auto-upgrade versions); by selecting "Devel" (for "make" tool). Once the download is done (and you are satisfied), you can install the downloaded packages from the local directory (by running the Cygwin Setup*.exe again, but this time asking it to install from local directory).

Answer (score 0):

Run the cygwin setup script again, it acts as their package manager and installer. You can download it from cygwin's website again if needed. It will ask where your packages are stored and won't reinstall anything. You select the versions of programs you would like installed, including make. You could also deselect all packages and only select make.

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding the usage of cygwin setup. By default it install only the base packages. Make does not belong to base and must be required.

Almost a duplicate of
[BC command not working in CYGWIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39054508/bc-command-not-working-in-cygwin/39061532#39061532)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `apt-cyg` command which is the equivalent of Linux's `apt-get`. Don't prefix it with a `sudo` though.