# echo "2+4"|bc not working in Cygwin

Tags: windows

I am running Cygwin on windows 7 32 bit. I need to calculate using a single command so, to do that i typed:
echo "2+4"|bc
This shows me:
-bash: bc: command not found.
Does anyone help me in getting the result.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BC command not working in CYGWIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39054508/bc-command-not-working-in-cygwin)

Comment: The `bc` command is not installed. You have to use the Cygwin setup to install the package that contains it.

Answer (score 0):

The command `bc` is probably not installed on your cygwin environment. You can use straight up bash calculation for simple math like that by doing `echo $((2+4))`.